# Error in Spark cassandra integration with spark-cassandra connector

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, sbt, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to save data in cassandra in a standalone mode from spark. By running following command:

```
  bin/spark-submit --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.6.0-s_2.10
     --class "pl.japila.spark.SparkMeApp" --master local  /home/hduser2/code14/target/scala-2.10/simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar
```

My build.sbt file is :-

```
**name := "Simple Project"    
version := "1.0"     
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"      
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.0"     
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.0"     
resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven"       
libraryDependencies += "datastax" % "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.6.0-s_2.10"       
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(        
  "org.apache.cassandra" % "cassandra-thrift" % "3.5" ,      
  "org.apache.cassandra" % "cassandra-clientutil" % "3.5",      
  "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "3.0.0"    
)**
```

My Spark code is :-

```
package pl.japila.spark     
import org.apache.spark.sql._    
import com.datastax.spark.connector._    
import com.datastax.driver.core._     
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql._   
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}    
import com.datastax.driver.core.QueryOptions._    
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf    
import com.datastax.driver.core._   
import com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd._   

object SparkMeApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

 val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")

  val sc = new SparkContext("local", "test", conf)    
  val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)    
  val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("test", "kv")    
  val collection = sc.parallelize(Seq(("cat", 30), ("fox", 40)))

collection.saveToCassandra("test", "kv", SomeColumns("key", "value"))
  }
}
```

And I got this error:-

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.QueryOptions.setRefreshNodeIntervalMillis(I)Lcom/datastax/driver/core/QueryOptions;**
>         at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.clusterBuilder(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:49)
>         at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.createCluster(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:92)
>         at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:153)
>         at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$3.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:148)
>         at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$3.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:148)
>         at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:31)
>         at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:56)
>         at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:81)
>         at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:109)

Versions used are :-
**Spark - 1.6.0

Scala - 2.10.4

cassandra-driver-core jar - 3.0.0

cassandra version 2.2.7

spark-cassandra connector - 1.6.0-s_2.10**

SOMEBODY PLEASE HELP !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by removing

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(        
  "org.apache.cassandra" % "cassandra-thrift" % "3.5" ,      
  "org.apache.cassandra" % "cassandra-clientutil" % "3.5",      
  "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "3.0.0"    
)
```

Since the libraries which are dependencies of the connector will be included automatically with the packages dependency.

Then I would test the packages resolution by launching the spark-shell with

```
./bin/spark-shell --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.6.0-s_2.10
```

you see the following resolutions happening correctly

```
datastax#spark-cassandra-connector added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
        confs: [default]
        found datastax#spark-cassandra-connector;1.6.0-s_2.10 in spark-packages
        found org.apache.cassandra#cassandra-clientutil;3.0.2 in list
        found com.datastax.cassandra#cassandra-driver-core;3.0.0 in list
        ...
        [2.10.5] org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.5
:: resolution report :: resolve 627ms :: artifacts dl 10ms
        :: modules in use:
        com.datastax.cassandra#cassandra-driver-core;3.0.0 from list in [default]
        com.google.guava#guava;16.0.1 from list in [default]
        com.twitter#jsr166e;1.1.0 from list in [default]
        datastax#spark-cassandra-connector;1.6.0-s_2.10 from spark-packages in [default]
        ...
```

If these appear to resolve correctly but everything still doesn't work, I would try clearing out the cache for these artifacts.

Comment: Thanks a lot Russ, I got my problem resolved. It was the cache issue.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what sort of cache this was related to and how you cleaned it? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: for sbt that's
~/.ivy2/cache/
maven is
~/.m2/repository/

You can either remove the contents of those directories or just remove the elements that it says it cannot find. Usually those directories will exist but will be missing some of the files.

Comment: Thank you, my problem was using the wrong version of Cassandra Java Driver, I followed this matrix and problem was resolved. https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#version-compatibility